# gcloud app deploy service restart audomatically

Tags: node.js, deployment, gcloud, restart

I recently deployed a Node JS app via

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Inside my code, I have setInterval that triggers a function every hour. Unfortunately, the deployed server automatically restarts and as the result, it destroys my timing function.  Anyone knows how could I prevent auto-restart for such deployment with gcloud?

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us how your code is calling the functions? What is the expected result? Do you see an Error message? Please share it

Comment: It was related to the fact that a free google cloud account PaaS service goes to idle automatically each 15 minutes if there is not any URL request from outside to the server

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to schedule this **outside** the GAE app itself. GAE is not meant to have functions triggered like you are doing. You need to use cron jobs for this.

How to do this is [very well documented.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)

Another option would be to run your code on a GCE instance instead.

Comment: I would also like to mentioned that additionally to GAE cronjobs, [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) is available to proc specifics tasks at determined time (as a cronjob does)